# Ionic Framework - Integrate side-menu with Introduction page getting issue

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

My introduction page has to open first time and then after it has to open side menu app. here I could able to display introduction page for the firsttime when app is installed, but the problem here i could able to display playlists page but navigation bar is not displaying.

Here is My Code:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ome1w3isn41hjch/menu.zip?dl=0

getting error in Mobile browser console like this

[image]

See the screen shot the nav-bar is empty

Answer (score 3):

bundle.js error shown because of injector error occupied in app.js
so check your app.js angular inject elements.

Answer (score 1):

you missed [ng-cordova.js](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/)

install using bower from above link..!and `<script src="lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>` in index.html

index.html

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

Comment: remove below lines from ur code : 
`<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.26/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.26/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>`

Comment: make sure `ng-cordova.min.js` is added and run the code on devices..with live-reload : ionic run android -c -s -l

Comment: By removing the above links the introduction page buttons got hidden. But the main page is working fine.